# Removing consecutive newlines with ed

Tags: newlines, ed

Input file:

```
1 line1\
2 line2\
3 line3\
4 \
5 line4\
6 \
7 \
8 line5\
```

Desired output:

```
1 line1
2 line2
3 line3
4
5 line4
6
7 line5
```

Is it possible with POSIX `ed`?

Removing the trailing backslashes is easy, but how can I also handle consecutive blackslashes as expected output?

Comment: The FAQ says "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."  Using `ed` for this instead of `sed | cat -s` doesn't seem practical or a problem that anyone would actually face, so I think this question should be closed.

Comment: I am asking `ed`, not your sed wise , cat squeeze I know very early.  I wrote Assembly LDA load accumlator in 1979. It is I want ed for the whole file read. If you are not there, well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not know how to do this in one go. But if the contents is well known one could add a unique string to double lines.

```
# Add XX to lines that should be deleted
g/^$/+1s/^$/XX/
# Delete them
g/XX/d
```

Not very nice tho.

Comment: Thank you! tested it and it works. Is `g/^$/+1s//XX/` the same thing?

Comment: @user28512 Yes, and so is `v/./+1s/^$/XX/`. Note that all those solutions would fail if the last-line is empty and would only remove two consecutive lines (use `v/./+1,/./s/^$/XX/` for more than two). Why would you want to use `ed` anyway?

Comment: You love`ed`? The `v` will kick me to grep's `v` of it is negate. Per POSIX line has to have a \n, not many people knows.   @Stephane Chazelalas please write some on `ed` for the public.

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`, you could do:

```
sed 's/\\$//;/./,/^$/!d'
```

One of the main problems with `ed` (beside its syntax from another age) is error handling in script.

Basically, you have to think of it as `ed` returns success if it successfully edited the file. But to be a successful edit, you have to have each commands address to be valid, each command to be successful (for instance, for the `s` command, that means at least one substitution done).

So, if you want to check that the edit was successful in this case, it can be tricky.

To build up on @Sukminder's solution and attempt to cover the corner cases, one could write:

```
printf '%s\n' a a . 'g/\\$/s///' ',s/^/a/' 'g/^a$/+1,/./s/^a$//' \
  'v/./d' 'g/^a/s///' '$d' w | ed -s the-file
```

The `g` command would fail if the file was empty (because the default address range (`1,$`) would be invalid, so we need first to add a line at the end of the file (with the `a` command). `,s/\\$//` would fail if there was no line ending in `\` so we need to run it only if there are such lines (`g/\\$/s///`).

Here, instead of inserting a "xx" assuming it's not to be found in the input, we prepend "a" to each line and replace the lines to be removed with an empty line which we remove afterwards.

Hopefully, that `ed` script will only return a non-zero exit status if it fails to write the file (`w` command failing). Unfortunately, I've seen `ed` implementations returning success when failing to write a file when the FS was full.

IMO, `ed` is best avoided. Nowadays, using `perl -pi.back` is as portable and more reliable.

Comment: thank you, but I am converting from sed to ed :)

Comment: My great appreciation for your very detail explanations.