# Does sed write to the file or give a sample output

Tags: linux, sed

when using `sed` with a file like this

```
sed 's/a/o' fruits
```

it gives the necessary output to the terminal but it does not change the contents in the file. How do I permanently change the file with the above substitution?

Comment: Just as a curiosity: the reason it does not change files by default is that it is a *s*tream *ed*itor :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-i` parameter to permamently change the file.

Comment: Thanx.. it works :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, you shouldn't. GNU coreutils and some other versions add an `-i` option for in-place editing, but it has varying implementations and is not portable. Files are not streams, so editing them with `sed` should be avoided. The `-i` option to `sed` also breaks any symlinks, since it essentially deletes it and recreates the file. Use `ed` or `ex` for a more sane alternative.

```
ex -s file << EOF
s/a/o/
w
EOF
```

Comment: +1 for portability warning. But beware of [caveats with ed as well](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58058/22565). For instance, if there's no "a" in the file, it will return a non-zero exit status and you can't tell if it's because of that or because the file couldn't be written.

Answer (score 0):

From the man page of sed:

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

          edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```